# cos(x) program confusion with function input

Tags: java

How would I finish this program?
I know it is wrong where I have inputed the calculation into the code. What do I need to change to get the program to work the way the assignment asks (see image)? Also where would I loop it to recalculate if the user chooses to at the end?

```
package cosx;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class cosx2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the degree: ");
    double degree = input.nextDouble(); 

    double radian = getRadian(degree);

    calculateCos(input, radian,degree);

}


public static double getRadian(double x) {      
    return x = (Math.PI/180)*x;     
}

private static void calculateCos(Scanner std, double rad, double deg) {
    System.out.print("How many terms do you want to calculate the cos: ");
    int terms = std.nextInt();
    double top;
    double bottom;
    double sum=0;

    for(int i = 0; i<= terms; ++i){
        top = Math.pow(-1, i);          
        bottom =1;
        int repeat = 2*i+1;
        for(int j = 1; j <= repeat; ++j){               
            bottom *= j; 
        }
        if(i%2 == 0)
            sum += (top/bottom);
        else
            sum -= (top/bottom);
    }
    System.out.printf("The sin (%.1f", deg);
    System.out.printf(") is %.6f", sum);        
     }
    }
```

Comment: What image? *"Also where would I loop it to recalculate if the user chooses to at the end?"* Wut?

Comment: i'm afraid i don't see the image

Comment: expected input vs actual?

Comment: I'm also noticing that your `calculateCos` function doesn't actually use the `rad` parameter

Comment: You would loop it around where you ask the user...exactly as you ask.